# Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Login page

Tags: reactjs

`auth.action.js`:

```
import axios from "axios"
import { API_BASE_URL } from "../../config/api"
import { LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAILURE, REGISTER_REQUEST, REGISTER_SUCCESS } from "./authenticationType"

export const loginUserAction = (loginData) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST })
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/auth/signin`, loginData.data)

        if (data.jwt) {
            localStorage.setItem("jwt", data.jwt)
        }
        console.log("login", data)
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data.jwt })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("--------", error)
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: error })
    }
}

export const registerUserAction = (loginData) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: REGISTER_REQUEST })
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/auth/signup`, loginData.data);
        if (data.jwt) {
            localStorage.setItem("jwt", data.jwt);
        }
        console.log("register------", data);
        dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: data.jwt });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("--------", error);
        dispatch({ type: REGISTER_FAILURE, payload: error });
    }
};
```

`authenticationType.js`:

```
export const LOGIN_REQUEST = "LOGIN_REQUEST";
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
export const LOGIN_FAILURE = "LOGIN_FAILURE";

export const REGISTER_REQUEST = "REGISTER_REQUEST";
export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = "REGISTER_SUCCESS";
export const REGISTER_FAILURE = "REGISTER_FAILURE";
```

`authReducer.js`:

```
import { LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAILURE, REGISTER_REQUEST, REGISTER_SUCCESS } from "./authenticationType";

const initialState = {
    jwt: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false
}

export const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_REQUEST:
        case REGISTER_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, loading: true, error: null }

        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, jwt: action.payload, loading: false, error: null }

        case LOGIN_FAILURE:
        case REGISTER_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { store } from './Redux/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

`Login.jsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { loginUserAction } from "../../Redux/Auth/auth.action";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const initialValues = { email: "", password: "" };
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email").required("Email is required"),
    password: Yup.string().min(6, "Password must be at least 6 characters").required("Password is required")
});

const Login = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (values) => {
        console.log("handle submit", values);
        dispatch(loginUserAction({ data: values }));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
                {({ dirty, isValid }) => (
                    <Form>
                        <div>
                            <Field
                                type="email"
                                name="email"
                                label="Email"
                                as={TextField}
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Field
                                type="password"
                                name="password"
                                label="Password"
                                as={TextField}
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name="password" component="div" />
                        </div>
                        <Button type="submit" disabled={!dirty || !isValid}>Submit</Button>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Problem:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. You may have misspelled an action type string constant.
>
> at dispatch (createStore.ts:206:1)
> at redux-thunk.mjs:9:1
> at dispatch (applyMiddleware.ts:54:1)
> at auth.action.js:6:1
> at redux-thunk.mjs:7:1
> at handleSubmit (Login.jsx:19:1)
> at Formik.tsx:862:1
> at Formik.tsx:1216:1
> at Formik.tsx:768:1